# Loading a stored datatable into a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

If an SQL connection is already created, and a data table is created that takes input from an excel sheet, how do I use the SP in order to load the data table into the datagridview on my desktop application (Visual Studio 2008, Sql Server 2005 are being used)?

Comment: attach the datatable as `DataSource` to the grid

Comment: So you have a `DataTable` filled with data and you need to show it in a `DataGridView`? Why do you need a Stored Procedure for that? Simply use `gridViewName.Source = dataTableName` :)

Comment: @Ranhiru I created an SP for it since I need to apply an average function to the excel sheet loaded before saving it to the datatable.

Comment: @V4Vendetta I tried doing so. Didn't work. Can you post the code in case I got it wrong please?

Comment: Can you expand on **Didn't work** part, is `AutoGenerateColumn=true` for your grid ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I cannot find the AutoGenerateColumn in the first place.

Comment: Please show some code on how you are doing this, something seems wrong which cannot be inferred unless the code is seen

Comment: Just found the AutoGenerateColumn property was in the InitializeComponent. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();//in your case it's filled already like below or any other method

c.Open();
using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT CO_COMP_ID as Company_Id,CO_COMP_NAME as Company_Name, CO_ACTIVE as Active_Status, CO_FILE_TYPE as Using_File_Type, CO_DESC as Description  FROM CompRegister", c))
{
     a.Fill(t);
     //dgvCompDet.DataSource = t;
     fnDeselectRow();
  }
 c.Close();
```

Give data table  as data source to datagrid

```
dgvCompDet.DataSource = t;
```